# NDK with stlport_shared for standalone binary?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I want to compile a standalone binary from C++ sources which use some basic STL stuff like string, vector and so on.

If I compile it with 'stlport_static' everything works fine.

However with 'stlport_shared' I get this error message when executing the binary on the device:
link_image[1965]: 14649 could not load needed library 'libstlport_shared.so' for '/data/prog' (load_library[1120]: Library 'libstlport_shared.so' not found)CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE

Any ideas?

Comment: Damn I must be blind.

I just realized that the stlport lib on my device in /system/lib is named 'libstlport.so' and not 'libstlport_shared.so' as expected by the linker.

I just tested it by copying the 'libstlport.so' to 'libstlport_shared.so' and now it works fine.

Any way to point the linker to use the 'libstlport.so'?

Answer (score 1):

on java code put static block with the loadlibrary of the libstlport_shared.so
on application.mk put app_stl - stlport_shared
on android.mk check if there is local_static_library with libstlport and ld_libs with static stl and remove in both case.

It should work now